# Failed to insert multiple tags on Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, many-to-many, eloquent

I want to insert a Post record with multiple tags so here's my code in Post@store:

```
$post = Post::create(array(
            'title' => $request->title,
            'body' => $request->body,
            'user_id' => Auth::id(),
        ));

        if($post && $request->tags)
        {
            $tagNames = explode(',', $request->tags);
            $tagIds = [];
            foreach($tagNames as $tagName)
            {
                $tag = Tag::firstOrCreate(['name'=>$tagName]);
                if($tag)
                {
                    $tagIds[] = $tag->id;
                }
            }

            $post->tags()->attach($tagIds);
        }
```

but it give me an errors `"Call to a member function attach() on null"`. when i'm checked in mysql the tags is already in there but i can't find any entry on my post_tag tables. here's my post model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id','title','slug','body','tags','category_id','featured'];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        $this->hasMany('App\Tag');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the call the `hasMany` in your `Post` model.

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Tag');
}
```

**Update**

You should use `belongsToMany` not `hasMany`.

Comment: now i got this errors "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()"

Comment: It should be `belongsToMany` not `hasMany`

Comment: great, thanks. can you update your answer with belongsToMany too? i will select it.